# Is it possible to get the value of another elements in CSS

Tags: html, css, height, width

I'm creating a mobi site and would like to set the height of some of my elements to a multiple of the width, sorry if I'm not coming off clear enough here is an example of what I want to do.

```
#myDiv{
width : 40%;
height : width * 1.4;
}
```

I initially was just going to set the height to +-50% but I later realized I loose the aspect ratio depending on the screen size of the phone.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php

Comment: Here is the problem with your question.  If CSS is not an option, the answer you will get is: "No", which does not solve your problem.  This begs the question, do you want a JavaScript or jQuery option? You have not said if you would consider this.  If you allow for more options, then the question may become more useful to others who may consider either a CSS or a JavaScript solution.  Please reconsider editing your question.  Thank-you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@cinnanon is right, this can't be done with CSS alone.

You could use jQuery (javascript), although this is probably not the best practice for building a responsive site:

```
var adjustHeight = 1.4;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div').css('height', ($('div').width() * adjustHeight));
});

$(window).resize(function () {
    $('div').css('height', ($('div').width() * adjustHeight));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/philsinatra/pqz59/

Comment: You forgot to mention that you need to apply this when ever you resize the window, which you do in your fiddle... and this does indeed make it responsive as long as js is enable, which is probably a fair assumption in this day and age.

Comment: I edited the code to reflect the additional resize function that will adjust the height as the window size changes.